# Java: how to use the Pattern class to extract pieces of an expression?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following pattern definition:

```
private static final String D = "(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun)";
private static final String DD = "(" + D + "-" + D + ")";
private static final String m_daysPattern = "(" + D + "|" + DD + ")(?:,(" + D + "|" + DD + "))*";
private static final Pattern m_daysRegex = Pattern.compile(m_daysPattern);
```

This regex should match expressions like these:

- "Mon-Fri"
- "Tue-Fri,Sun"
- "Mon-Wed,Fri-Sun"

I did it pretty easily in .NET using named groups, but here in Java 6 I am a bit lost. Can anyone show me an example of a code, which would allow me to extract the days and understand exactly which ranges and single days are mentioned in the given expression?

Thanks.

**EDIT1**

OK, here is what I get examining the groups of `m_daysRegex.matcher("Mon-Fri")`:

```
matchDays.groupCount() = 10
matchDays.groups = [0,7,0,7,-1,-1,0,7,0,3,4,7,-1,...,-1] (22 values)
matchDays.group(0) = "Mon-Fri"
matchDays.group(1) = "Mon-Fri"
matchDays.group(2) = null
matchDays.group(3) = "Mon-Fri"
matchDays.group(4) = "Mon"
matchDays.group(5) = "Fri"
matchDays.group(6) = null
matchDays.group(7) = null
matchDays.group(8) = null
matchDays.group(9) = null
matchDays.group(10) = null
```

Can someone explain to me the logic of all this? I mean not only should I get "Mon" and "Fri", but I also have to know that they are part of a range subexpression "Mon-Fri", rather than just "Mon,Fri".

BTW, matching "Mon,Fri" gives us this:

```
matchDays.groupCount() = 10
matchDays.groups = [0,7,0,3,0,3,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,4,7,4,7,-1,...,-1] (22 values)
matchDays.group(0) = "Mon,Fri"
matchDays.group(1) = "Mon"
matchDays.group(2) = "Mon"
matchDays.group(3) = null
matchDays.group(4) = null
matchDays.group(5) = null
matchDays.group(6) = "Fri"
matchDays.group(7) = "Fri"
matchDays.group(8) = null
matchDays.group(9) = null
matchDays.group(10) = null
```

It is different, which is good. Still I find it hard to understand the algorithm.

This is quite easy in .NET, so I was expecting something as easy in Java. Fair, no?

**EDIT2**

Is there a Java regex guide explaining this stuff? All the guides I have seen so far examine really simple regular expressions.

**EDIT3**

OK, I begin to get it. My regex can be depicted like this:

```
 (          // 1 = D1|D2-D3
  (D1)|     // 2 = D1
  (         // 3 = D2-D3
   (D2)-    // 4 = D2
   (D3)     // 5 = D3
  )
 )
 (?:,
  (         // 6 = D4|D5-D6
   (D4)|    // 7 = D4
   (        // 8 = D5-D6
    (D5)-   // 9 = D5
    (D6)    // 10 = D6
   )
  )
 )*
```

It explains the group values for "Mon-Fri" and "Mon,Fri". But how are the repetitions handled? For instance, "Mon,Wed,Fri" ? Still trying to figure it out.

**EDIT4**

I now get it. I can match a complex regex with repetitions, but I cannot extract the respective matches easily - must iterate using the `find()` method and a simpler subregex. So, in my case I have decided to:

1. Match the entire expression to make sure it is valid
2. Split it (with `StringUtils.split` from apache) by ','
3. Iterate the split parts, splitting by '-' if necessary.

Thanks to all the good Samaritans out there for all the help.

Comment: I wouldn't use a RegExp at all to parse such simple strings. What are you trying to achieve? Do you just need to know, if the string matches the "pattern" or do you need to "understand" the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a description of capturing groups etc, go here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

As for your pattern, if you write out all parantheses you get:

```
((d)|((d)-(d)))(?:,((d)|((d)-(d))))*
```

where d is

```
Mon|Tue|...
```

Listing the groups, using M to show which parts that belong to a given group:

```
 0 - the matching string, if there is one
 1 - ((M)|((M)-(M)))(?:,((d)|((d)-(d))))*
 2 - ((M)|((d)-(d)))(?:,((d)|((d)-(d))))*
 3 - ((d)|((M)-(M)))(?:,((d)|((d)-(d))))*
 4 - ((d)|((M)-(d)))(?:,((d)|((d)-(d))))*
 5 - ((d)|((d)-(M)))(?:,((d)|((d)-(d))))*
 6 - ((d)|((d)-(d)))(?:,((M)|((M)-(M))))*
 7 - ((d)|((d)-(d)))(?:,((M)|((d)-(d))))*
 8 - ((d)|((d)-(d)))(?:,((d)|((M)-(M))))*
 9 - ((d)|((d)-(d)))(?:,((d)|((M)-(d))))*
10 - ((d)|((d)-(d)))(?:,((d)|((d)-(M))))*
```

Given the string "Mon-Fri" you'll get the strings you see in the output, i.e.

```
 0 - Mon-Fri i.e. the full match
 1 - Mon-Fri i.e. ((M)|((M)-(M)))
 2 - null i.e. not matched by (M)
 3 - Mon-Fri i.e. ((M)-(M))
 4 - Mon i.e. the first (M) in group 3
 5 - Fri i.e. the second (M) in group 3
 6 - and so on...
```

For multiple matches you'll do something like

```
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    // extract groups from m
}
```

EDIT: come to think of it, you probably don't need the last part, i.e.

```
(?:,((d)|((d)-(d))))*
```

in your pattern. Just use the while loop with the

```
(d)|((d)-(d))
```

pattern to find each part (i.e. the stuff between the commas).

Comment: Very nice, thanks. But what about the repetitions? Like in "Mon,Wed,Fri"?

Comment: Will it match something like "Mon-FriblablablaWed-Thu"? The first `find()` is going to match "Mon-Fri" and the next one - "Wed-Thu", allowing for the garbage in between, isn't it?

Comment: I have decided to match the entire regex and then just split by ',' iterate and split by '-' if needed using `StringUtils.split`.

Comment: If you're referring to my simplified pattern then yes, it will allow (but skip) the garbage. I.e. it cannot be used to verify that the input string is formatted correctly.

Comment: But I get the picture now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

groups in java regex are accessed using index, the index is the counter of the opening parenthesis.

here is an example (of something i worked on earlier) that works on groups in java. Hope this helps.

```
/**
 * <li>range={0,2} -&gt; 0 to 2 
 * <li>range={3,n} -&gt; 3 to Integer.MAX_VALUE
 * <li>range={7} -&gt; 0 to 7
 * <li>range={n} -&gt; 0 to Integer.MAX_VALUE
 * <li>range={-n} -&gt; Integer.MIN_VALUE to 0
 */
@Test
public void getRange() {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
        "\\{" +
        "([+-]?(n|[0-9])){1}" + // group 1
        "(" +
        "(,){1}" +
        "([+-]?(n|[0-9])){1}" + // group 5
        "){0,1}" +
        "\\}");

    Matcher m = null;
    String range = null;

    logger.debug("pattern: " + p.pattern());

    range = "{0,2}";
    m = p.matcher(range);
    logger.debug(range + " -> groupCout: " + m.groupCount());
    printGroups(m);
    Assert.assertEquals("0", m.group(1));
    Assert.assertEquals("2", m.group(5));

    range = "{3,n}";
    m = p.matcher(range);
    logger.debug(range + " -> groupCout: " + m.groupCount());
    printGroups(m);
    Assert.assertEquals("3", m.group(1));
    Assert.assertEquals("n", m.group(5));

    range = "{7}";
    m = p.matcher(range);
    logger.debug(range + " -> groupCout: " + m.groupCount());
    printGroups(m);
    Assert.assertEquals("7", m.group(1));
    Assert.assertEquals(null, m.group(5));

    range = "{n}";
    m = p.matcher(range);
    logger.debug(range + " -> groupCout: " + m.groupCount());
    printGroups(m);
    Assert.assertEquals("n", m.group(1));
    Assert.assertEquals(null, m.group(5));

    range = "{-3,-7}";
    m = p.matcher(range);
    logger.debug(range + " -> groupCout: " + m.groupCount());
    printGroups(m);
    Assert.assertEquals("-3", m.group(1));
    Assert.assertEquals("-7", m.group(5));
}

private void printGroups(Matcher m) {
    if(m != null && m.matches()) {
        for(int i = 0; i < m.groupCount()+1; i++) {
            logger.debug("group " + i + ": " + m.group(i));

        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Your expressions are too simple - they contain neither repetitions nor alternations. I am sorry, but I cannot learn by it.

Comment: i don't / can't know if you can learn by that that but i think it answers your question about dealing `groups in java regex` and wishing to have an `example`. Examples should be simple. isnt this what you ended up doing ... accessing goups via index ? rhetorical question ...